# MySQL math to get Top 3 scores

Tags: mysql

I'm doing a website for a Fantasy Movie League and what I'm trying to do is get the Top 3 Total Scores overall

Total scores should be: The sum of various points for each players's active movies DIVIDED BY the number of that player's active movies

(So if a player has 300 points from active movies and has 3 active movies, the answer should be 100)

So my question is: How do I calculate the individual player's number of active movies (in the subquery) without specifying the player_id?

```
SELECT 
players.id as player_id,
first_name, last_name,
(metacritic + (imdb*10) + top_bottom + power(receipts,(2/9)) + ticket + oscar_noms + oscar_wins + gg_noms + gg_wins + isa_noms + isa_wins + razzie_noms + razzie_wins + festival_points + ifca_points) / (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM movies WHERE release_date >= CURDATE() and year_id=1 and player_id=4) as player_active_movie_total
FROM movies
INNER JOIN players on players.id=movies.player_id
WHERE release_date >= CURDATE() and year_id=1
ORDER BY player_active_movie_total DESC
LIMIT 3
```

Comment: you need to add a GROUP BY and do a SUM on the ID in the movies table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a subQuery in your select statement. Based on your criteria you just need to use a GROUP BY statement and a COUNT on ID. The query below will NOT work because you need grouping/sum on each column, but should point you in the right direction

```
SELECT players.id as player_id, first_name, last_name,
(metacritic + (imdb*10) + top_bottom + power(receipts,(2/9)) + ticket + oscar_noms +     oscar_wins + gg_noms + gg_wins + isa_noms + isa_wins + razzie_noms + razzie_wins +     festival_points + ifca_points) / 
(COUNT(id)) as player_active_movie_total
FROM movies
 INNER JOIN players on players.id=movies.player_id
WHERE release_date >= CURDATE() and year_id=1
GROUP BY players.id, first_name, last_name
ORDER BY player_active_movie_total DESC
LIMIT 3
```

Your metacritic column (and all other in the SELECT list) either need to be part of an aggregate function i.e. `SUM` or `COUNT` or `MAX` or listed in the `GROUP BY` statement like players.id is. I'm assuming you're wanting some sort of SUM on that entire column

Comment: Could you give me a hint as to what you mean by grouping each column? Trying without success :/

Comment: i added an extra comment to my answer that should help

Comment: Yes! I added SUM in front of (metacritic) and it seems to work properly now... you are the man